# twitter API, only pull users last tweet, python

Tags: python, api, twitter, pull

im using python and the twitter api v2 to pull the latest tweet of a specific account every few seconds.

the method im using though cant pull less than 10 tweets which uses up my twitter api rate limit too fast.

```
client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token= API_BEARER)
query = username
tweets = client.search_recent_tweets(query=query, tweet_fields=['context_annotations', 'created_at'], max_results=10)
```

this is what im using. is there any way to just pull the most recent tweet to save on api requests?

Also I've been looking at selenium/beautifulsoup to pull tweets and I've found a library which does this but each request takes about 20 secs, is that normal for selenium?

Comment: Not to sound like a smartass, but I assume you tried `max_results=1` and it didn't work?

Comment: Okay I see in the [docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/api-reference/get-tweets-search-recent) that it can't be less than 10 alright

Comment: yeah, sadly 10 is the least.